# GraphClientService throws exception when calling 'Any'

Tags: azure-active-directory

Given a GUID, I need to know if a user exists in azure active directory.

If I pass the Id of an exisitng user everything is Ok.
If I pass the id for which no user account exists, I get the following exeption:

> ServiceException: Code: Request_ResourceNotFound Message: Resource
> '02803255-b96e-438a-9123-123' does not exist or one of its queried
> reference-property objects are not present.

I know this record doen not exist, as this is what I'm testing, I want false to be returned somehow.
Surely I do not have to catch the exception?

```
//Simple code:
    public bool CheckUserExists(string userId) {
        bool exists = false;
        //purposefully set this to a string that does not match any user.
        userId = "02803255-b96e-438a-9123-123";
        var user = _graphServiceClient
            .Users
            .Request()
            .Filter("Id eq '" + userId + "'")
            .GetAsync();
        //exception thrown on next line.
        if (user.Result.Count == 1) {
            exists = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try checking if user count is less than or equals 0 condition , instead if count equals 1.

```
    var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
         var exists=true;
       try {
                var user = _graphServiceClient
                  .Users
                  .Request()
                  .Filter("Id eq '" + userId + "'")
                  .GetAsync(); 


             if (user.Count <= 0) {
                   exists = false;
                      break;
                         }
            } 
      catch (ServiceException ex) {
           exists = false;
                        }

return exists;
```

or try with

```
 if (user.Count !=null && user.Count>=0)
```

**Reference:**

1. [verify if user account exists in azure active directory -SO
   reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58380915/verify-if-user-account-exists-in-azure-active-directory)
2. [Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/User](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/User/-/php-user-class-examples.html#0x05e7ba5fcd66f6624f66a5154dad09ce1facbb3478a6b42478d81f66e13e4db6-64,,111,)